# How to solve this problem in passive form

Tags: passive-voice

> How to solve this problem?

Can we make its Passive form?

I changed it like this,

> How is this problem to be solved?

Correct me,  please.

Comment: Your sentence is idiomatic and needs no correction.

Comment: How to make its Passive voice?

Comment: "This problem is solved *how*?" though this would be very non-standard. *How to solve this problem?* itself is a problem, because it is not a complete sentence. Normally it might be "How *do you* solve this problem?", since problems generally don't solve themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with

> How is this problem solved?

No "to be".

To be passive only requires "problem" to be the object of the verb ("solved"). It's over complicating it to also make the verb an infinitive ("to be").

Comment: Could you please give us some idea as to why?

Comment: How this problem to solved? I think, this is a correct passive voice.  Or how  should this problem be solved?

Comment: Sorry,  How this problem to be solved?  Correct

Comment: @user124234: Unless that's just another typo on your part, you need to know that "How this problem to be solved?" is not valid English at all. You must include the finite verb form ***is*** after ***how***, regardless of whether you follow Dylan's sound advice to forget about the pointless verbosity of the additional infinitive.